# I get the red circle with the white line

Tags: error-handling

This is what it says:

An ocurred, please run Package Manager from right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was:

```
Error:Opening the cache(E:Encountered a section with no Package:header,
E:Problem with  MergeList/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_security_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en
E:The package lists or status file could not be  parsed or opened.)'.
This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies
```

I tried the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

But still I have not fixed it.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: user164131, from the post Jorge linked, another person said they had to try those two commands several times, but that it did eventually work. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands in a shell and see what the response is:

`apt-get check`

`apt-get -f install`

Comment: This is what I get now:

Comment: There is nothing in your comment. You get nothing?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaccounts-qt5-1 libdee-qt5-3 libllvm3.1:i386 libqt5graphicaleffects5 libqt5network5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5svg5 libqt5v8-5
  libqt5xml5 libsignon-qt5-1 libudev0:i386 libwebp2:i386 qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-friends-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme

Comment: Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.

Comment: So then I did:  apt-get autoremove, but still is not fixed

Comment: Did you do the `apt-get -f install` as well?

Comment: yes I did do it

Comment: Have you made any changes recently to apt-get or your repository configuration that could have triggered this?

Comment: sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_main_i18n_Translation-en ~/extras.backup

Comment: This is the only thing I did, apart from what I said before